# Display PDF with Phonegap - multiplatform

Tags: android, iphone, pdf, cordova, windows-phone-7.1

I'm trying to make an mobile app with phonegap that can open(and save) PDF files from the internet.
This app should run on Iphone, android and windows phone (that's why I choose Phonegap)

I think I tried everything I could find but I am unable to make this happen on the devicies.
I have control over the webservice that's providing the PDF (aspx).

Does anyone has an example maybe how to do this?
I tried ChildBrowser plugin but also with no luck.
I can open websites (http://www.etc.com) but when I try to open a PDF(http**s**://something.com?GetPDF.aspx) I only see a white window in the cildbrowser plugin.
With HTML5 object en embed tag I have also no luck in displaying PDF.

Any help would be great, because at this point I'm stuck!!

Answer (score 0):

In cordova-2.5.0 I just use open.window and pass an external PDF to google like this:

```
onClick="window.open('http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://yoursite.com/thepdf.pdf','_blank', 'location=no'); return false;
```

Then the pdf opens with the phonegap [InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html). 
Very basic, but allows for a more standardized experience between iOS and Android.

Answer (score -1):

U need first download file, then create file explorer where u opened this pdf file, or u opened file from internet, then u need try this code:

```
childbrowser = ChildBrowser.install(); // create child browser
 var strrrPath = "http://www.section508.gov/docs/pdfguidanceforgovernment.pdf";
var path = strPath.substr(0,strPath.lastIndexOf('/')); //added file path - addres to file
childbrowser.showWebPage(encodeURI(path)); //open file
```

Comment: Hi dajver,
Thank you for your time and answer.
This is not working, I do not see the PDF file in the childbrowser.
The path the childbroswer opens is "ht tp://www.section508.gov/docs";
Not the PDF file.
Am I missing something?

Comment: You added to your project child browser files? Maybe you forgot to add the javascript file in the project? I currently do not have X code but you may need to do this:


`childbrowser = ChildBrowser.install(); // create child browser
var strPath = "http://www.section508.gov/docs/pdfguidanceforgovernment.pdf";
childbrowser.showWebPage(strPath); //open file`

Comment: Hi dajver,
Yes, I did and childbrowser.js is defined in the head.
I also see the childbrowser coming up but the content is white (no PDF).
I tried this on Windows Phone and Android without any luck so far.
Thank you.